# Run edge in private on browser stack

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge, browserstack

I am new to browser stack and trying to execute edge in private mode on browser stack. I am trying to do it with following code but it's launching in normal mode whatsoever.

```
caps.setCapability("os_version", osVersion);
            caps.setCapability("os", os);
            caps.setCapability("resolution", "1920x1080");
            caps.setCapability("browser", browser);
            caps.setCapability("browser_version", browserVersion);
            if(isPrivate && browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.addArguments("incognito");
                caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
            }
            else if(isPrivate && browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
                EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
                edgeOptions.setCapability("InPrivate",true);
                caps.merge(DesiredCapabilities.edge().merge(edgeOptions));
            }
```

I am using the following versions in pom and unfortunately can't upgrade at the moment:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
```

For anyone looking for a solution. I manage to achieve this by adding

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.edge</groupId>
        <artifactId>msedge-selenium-tools-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then

```
import com.microsoft.edge.seleniumtools.EdgeOptions;


EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.addArguments("inprivate");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest installing the **Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge** since you're using Selenium 3.141.59. You can follow the instruction here:
https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools#java

To enable inprivate mode, you can try the following sample code:

```
edgeOptions.addArguments("-inprivate")
```